# Android TextView Lines Collection

Tags: android, widget

I have a TextView that has 10 lines as a property and two variables, Alpha and Beta.

I want Alpha to use the first two lines of the TextView and Beta use the remainder of the lines or 3-10.

How do I code my Java?  I cannot find a way to directly address the Lines collection.

This does not work:

```
TextView.setText.Lines[1]("This is a test\n for Alpha");
TextView.setText.Lines[3]("This is a test\n for Beta\n that has more lines\n than Alpha");
```

TiA Trey

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Dmon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, the lines depend on the width of the TextView. If you want, you can use two TextViews, one with 2 lines and another one with 8.